# Expunged messages are not removed from trash, so expunge does not (always) permanently remove them

Tags: jakarta-mail

I have a client app which listens for added and removed messages from some mailboxes and folders.

There is the possibility to delete a message, I mean marking it as DELETED and [expunging](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/Folder.html#expunge--) it.
Sometimes a user may enter in its web mail client and delete a message (I mean moving it in trash, I'm not talking about GMail which behaves differently)
When such an event happens, the first expunge called by code, returns an array of expunged messages, which contains those messages deleted from web client too, why?
If it is correct, the expected result shouldn't be that expunged messages were permanently removed from trash too? After the expunge messages removed by user via web client, exist yet in trash.

Is it normal? I am a bit confused about expunction...
Thanks

Comment: Are you actually seeing the expunged **messages** in your trash folder?  Or are you just seeing the JavaMail Message objects that are referenced in the event?  In the latter case the Message objects allow you to synchronize any local cache with the messages that have been removed.  Most of the operations on a removed message will throw MessageRemovedException.

Comment: Yes I see them in trash folder.
More precisely, the one that I delete programmatically (marking DELETED and expunging folder) is removed from trash, it is really permanently deleted.
The others, previously deleted from web mail, and located in Trash folder, remain and are perfectly visible in Trash folder, despite of the fact that they are present in the array of Message returned by expunge method of my IMAPFolder.

Should they be permanently removed or not? If not, why expunge method return them? Thanks